# ifstream::open() function using a string as the parameter

Tags: c++, string, fstream, ifstream

I'm trying to make a program that asks for the file that they user would like to read from, and when I try to `myfile.open(fileName)` I get the error: "no matching function for call to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&)'`" at that line.

```
string filename;
cout<<"Enter name of file: ";
cin>>filename;
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open(filename); //where the error occurs.
myFile.close();
```

Comment: Annoyingly, cplusplus.com fails to mention that `open` has a `string` overload since C++11, while cppreference.com *does* indeed make that clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the previous version of C++ (C++03), `open()` takes only a `const char *` for the first parameter, instead of `std::string`. The correct way of calling it would then be:

```
myFile.open(filename.c_str());
```

In current C++ (C++11) that code is fine, though, so see if you can tell your compiler to enable support for it.

Comment: Even CodeBlocks doesn't support passing a string variable to the "open" method. Had to use the ".c_str()" for it to work.